# Replace id numbers in rows based on the match between two columns

Tags: r, dataframe, match

I am dealing with a data on club membership where each `row` represents a club's membership in one of the 10 student clubs, and the `length` of non-empty `column` represents the membership "size" of that club. Each non-empty cell of the data frame is filled with a "random number" denoting a student's membership in a club (random numbers were used to suppress their identities).
By default, each club has at least one member but not all students are registered as club members (some have no involvement in any clubs). The data looks like this (the data displayed at below contains only part of the data):

```css
club_id mem1 mem2 mem3 mem4 mem5 mem6 mem7
1       339    520  58    
2       700      
3        80    434     
4       516    811 471    
5        20      
6       211     80 439    516  305
```

I want to replace those random numbers with student ids (without revealing their real names) based on the match between the random numbers assigned to them and their student ids; however, only some of the students ids are matched to the random numbers assigned to those students.

I compiled them into a dataframe of 2 columns, which is available [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/nc98i784r91ugin/match.csv?dl=1) and looks like

```css
match <- read.csv("https://www.dropbox.com/s/nc98i784r91ugin/match.csv?dl=1")

head(match)
  id  rn
1  1 700
2  2 339
3  3 540
4  4  58
5  5 160
6  6 371
```

where column `rm` means random number.

So the tasks I am having trouble with are to 
(1) match and replace the random numbers on the dataframe with their corresponding student ids
(2) set those unmatched random number as `NA`

It will be really appreciated if someone could enlighten me on this.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I got the logic right. I replicated only a short version of your initial table and replaced the first number with 1000 (because that is a number that has no matching id).

```
club2 <- data.frame(club_id = 1:6, mem2 = c(1000, 700, 80, 516, 20, 211))

match <- read.csv("https://www.dropbox.com/s/nc98i784r91ugin/match.csv?dl=1")
```

Then, for the column `mem2`, I check if it exists in `match$rn`. If that is not the case, an NA is inserted. If that is the case, however, it inserts `match$id` - the one at the position where `match$rn` is equal to the number in `mem2`.

```
club2$mem2 <- ifelse(club2$mem2 %in% match$rn == TRUE, match$id[match(club2$mem2, match$rn)], NA)
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your suggestion! Is there anyway to implement a row-wise version of this? Since the data I have is organized in row-wise manner. One way I could think about is to remove the `club_id` column (such that those values won't be treated as student id), then remove all headers and finally transpose the dataframe and run your suggested code. But there might be easier way to achieve this.

Comment: I guess there are a lot of people around who would like to set my computer on fire for this, but I would probably use a for loop and iterate through columns.